# Detect innermost web element in (nested) in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, recursion

I am looking for getting the inner most web element in a page, when there are similar nested Webelements in a page.

Consider the example below:

```
<body>
    <table id="level1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="level2">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table id="level3">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <p>Test</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="level1_table2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="level2_table2">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</body>
```

So when I do a search on the page by Driver.findElements by tag "table" and which have some text - "Test",

I will get 5 WebElements in total, namely - `"level1", "level3" , "level1_table2" , "level2_table2"`

What I want to achieve is to have a list of innermost(nested) elements which satisfy my search criteria .

So the List I should get should only have 2 WebElements namely -  `"level3" and "level2_table2".`

I am looking something probably on the lines of recursion. Can somebody help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need recursion - everything you need is the proper XPath expression:

```
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("table[not(.//table)]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this strategy:

1. Search WebElements containing text `Test`
2. For each WebElement search for the first parent which match tag name is `table`

Here is in Java:

```
List<WebElement> elementsWithTest = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Test')]"));
List<WebElement> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(WebElement element : elementsWithTest) {
    WebElement parent = element.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
    while (! "table".equals(parent.getTagName())) {
        parent = parent.findElement(By.xpath(".."));
    }

    if ("table".equals(parent.getTagName())) {
        result.add(parent);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: doesnt give the expected result

Comment: @RahulRaina what do you mean ? it returns 2 elements: "level3" and "level2_table2".

Comment: yes it should that, but it is returning 6 elements.

Comment: Could you give me the output of `for(WebElement e : result){System.out.println(e.getTagName() + " " + e.getAttribute("id") + " " + e.getText());}` ? In my case it's working as expected.